# How to align several assignments in vim

Tags: c, vim

I have this piece of C code:

```
options->file_extension = DEFAULT_FILE_EXTENSION;
options->config = "";
options->max_file_bytes = DEFAULT_MAX_FILE_BYTES;
options->msg_sort_type = SORT_TYPE_NONE;
options->msg_sort_buffer_max_size = DEFAULT_SORT_BUFFER_MAX_SIZE;
options->msg_sort_buffer_flush_time = DEFAULT_SORT_BUFFER_FLUSH_TIME;
```

Is there any easy way in vim to align this so it becomes e.g. ?

```
options->file_extension             = DEFAULT_FILE_EXTENSION;
options->config                     = "";
options->max_file_bytes             = DEFAULT_MAX_FILE_BYTES;
options->msg_sort_type              = SORT_TYPE_NONE;
options->msg_sort_buffer_max_size   = DEFAULT_SORT_BUFFER_MAX_SIZE;
options->msg_sort_buffer_flush_time = DEFAULT_SORT_BUFFER_FLUSH_TIME;
```

Or even if I wrote the first line here as

```
options->file_extension             = DEFAULT_FILE_EXTENSION;
options->config|<--cursor her now
```

Would there be a quick way to jump the cursor on the 2. line up to the `=` of the previous line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Align](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Align) and I think it does the job:

- Whole file: `:Align =`
- Visual line: `<leader>t=` or `:'<,'>Align =` (i.e. `:` from visual line).

There's also [Tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular):

- Whole file: `:Tab /=`
- Visual line: `<leader>a=`

***PS:** Tabular seems to be the most popular choice, but I can't tell why. Is there something with it that Align doesn't do?*

Comment: I personally use Tabular. I find that Align provides too many mappings. I would much prefer a ex-command approach with named alignments. That way I could map only what I want/need.

Answer (score 1):

there are alignment plugins. I use the "old?" [Align](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294)

for your example, you can visual select your lines, and press `<leader>t=` You will get your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick, non-robust, vimmy, non-plugin way to accomplish this task, consider the following command

```
.,+6s/\(\S*\)\s*=/\=submatch(1) . repeat(' ', 15 - len(submatch(1))) . '='
```

Analysis by component:

```
.,+6s
```

substitute command over the appropriate range

```
/\(\S*\)\s*=/
```

Pattern (regular expression) designed to match LHS of assignment (as many non-space characters as possible followed by as many space characters as possible followed by an assignment operator (=))

```
\=
```

Starts the "sub-replace-expression" context.  Vim will "evaluate" the expression and use it to replace the matched text.

```
submatch(1) .
```

In the "sub-replace-expression" context, `submatch(1)` will be replaced with the first submatch (similar to `\1`).  The `.` is the concatenation operator.

```
repeat(' ', 15 - len(submatch(1)))
```

This expression does the "heavy lifting" of alignment.  `repeat` will create a list or string depending on the first argument, the `' '` says "repeat a single space", and `15-len(submatch(1))` says "repeat it that many times."  Of course, 15 could be replaced with whatever column + initial nonspace character the assignments should be aligned at.

```
. '='
```

Puts the assignment operator back on.  Note that we can't just type `=`, because this is an expression, so to add it we must "concatenate it" with `. '='`.

I say this is "non-robust," because as is it won't work with definitions (declarations with assignments), which is probably desirable.  However, by changing the initial regular expression, a great deal of flexibility can be obtained.  It's also worth knowing, because it exposes a pretty powerful tool within vim, and can probably do a lot of good work without having to depend on a plugin.

Further reading:

```
:help :sub-replace-expression
:help :repeat()
```

Comment: Also, there may be a more elegant way to do this with printf or 'comments' or 'format-expression', but this is for me the most direct way...